# How to handle an employee being forced in to Team

Tags: united-kingdom, employees, team-role

I work in a small sized company as part of an IT Team of 5, which includes 2 software developers.

A person was introduced to the company by a member staff as a potential hire as a software developer. We declined this persons initial application on the basis that he was not experienced enough and would not be a good fit for the team. This person then went on to join another team within the business.

This person has subsequently created a web application to assist in a process within the team they work for. We are being asked to allow this person to deploy and maintain this application.

This person will not be part of IT and remain where they are in the organization. IT will have no input to this person work schedule etc.

I am very hesitant to allow this application to be deployed and used, although the person insists that it works very well.

It feels like we are slowly being forced to accept this person on to the team, despite the fact we do not feel they would be suitable.

I am at a bit of loss as to how we handle this situation?

EDIT: I feel I should clarify some points:

1. The person was not hired as a developer in another team. They have a general administrative role.
2. The project they have created *does* add value to that specific team but was not assigned to us to develop initially as we have other higher priority projects.
3. The person is a friend of friend to a member of senior management.
4. The person was not offered a developer role as quite simply they did not have the required skillset that we were looking for.
5. The application has been reviewed and while some parts of the application are ok and have potential, there are concerns about the rest of the application.
6. The application in its current form does duplicate some maintenance and ongoing tasks that already exist in our core system.

My concerns with this are that I do not want to set a precedent that it is perfectly fine for areas of the business to develop their own applications and expect IT to support them.

The application is not at the standard that we would want to release in to production.

We are very stretched for resources as it is without having the added burden of taking on an application that will need to be fully reviewed and refactored prior to deployment.

I'd like to avoid having some hybrid role whereby this person is under the management of someone else but does a bit of IT on the side. (I think someone mentioned the term "Shadow IT" for this)

A possible solution to this would be to take some aspects of this project and integrate them in to our core system.

Comment: Why didn't IT develop and deploy the (apparently needed) application earlier?

Comment: Are you in a position to be able to affect any change? If not, then there isn't anything you can do. Many times we need to work with people we don't like or don't feel are qualified. Many times we need to work with tools, processes, and policies we don't agree with. This is the nature of being an employee.

Comment: Did your manager, his boss, or someone up in the management chain ask you to take this person and his web app into your team ? If yes, try to explain your concern to the boss with technical facts.

Comment: @JonCuster The project was not deemed high enough priority to allocate the existing resources to.

Comment: "an IT Team of 5, made up of 2 software developers"  a team of 5 with 2 people in it?  But back on topic, bosses get to tell workers what to do.  If you don't like it, talk to the boss or quit.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the deployment of the web application requires your permission.

Comment: This is called "Shadow IT" and you need to stamp it out right now, you need to ask awkward questions like how this will be maintained when the employee is off sick / on holiday etc, what the plan is when they leave etc etc. Basically all the stuff you cover as a department.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "being forced into team". The individual is in their own team; you are merely consuming their output, as you do any other tools you use. If it works well and they support it well, that isn't a problem; the fact that you didn't hire them into your own group is completely irrelevant. If either of those isn't true, and they can't fix it, your manager complains to their manager and either the tool gets fixed by someone else or abandoned.

Comment: "It feels like" is *your* problem.

Comment: I vote to close this because it is a rant and not a question.  Dont think i have seen such entitled attitude on this forum yet

Comment: @deep64blue - It’s not the author’s responsibility to stomp it out, if their manager, is saying support it they should support it. If the author’s manager or someone directly responsible for making this decision is making the request, and in reality the employee is asking the author to support it, then their manager can make the decision

Comment: The business needs it, you're too busy, so someone else does it and will maintain it in future - but you seem both to expect the business simply to put everything on hold until your small under-resourced team is ready, _and_ be choosy as to not taking more people into the team?

Comment: See, this "expect IT to support them" is what you have left completely out of your question. Who told you to support the application? What support will be needed that [person] is unable to provide? Have you actually had a conversation with your boss about this?

Answer (score 8):

There is no universally "correct" action in this sort of situation. The specific circumstances, policies, and people all affect the dynamic in substantial ways. With that disclaimer out of the way, there are some places to start.

The most important thing throughout this all is to **be objective** and **communicate**. Make your decisions based on your role, your responsibilities, and your professional expertise. Here is what I can suggest based on the situation as described:

1. There is a curious feature to this situation which is that the new employee created an application that is apparently useful and important. This begs the question: why wasn't the IT department asked to work on this application? There may be some structural weaknesses in the company or just some basic poor communication. This is worth a conversation or three.
2. Exceptions. Deploying and maintaining an application outside of the normal IT process is usually a bad idea. Any sort of "special case" is likely to cause problems or at least consume more time and resources to maintain and manage. Figure out what this means **specifically** in your case, and make sure all the parties understand what additional burdens they are creating.
3. Objections. Do you have specific objections to the application itself, or only that it is operating outside of your department? If the former, bring those up. If the latter, come up with a plan to bring the app (not the employee) into your department. If you have standards that must be met (testing, automation, integration), lay them out. Is it possible for IT to take ownership of this app?
4. Responsibilities. If someone outside of IT is doing IT work, this should be discussed with management. Either the IT department is underperforming or they are overreaching. There's a reason for organizations to have distinct departments. There may also be room for people to work across departments depending on the company. What are your specific concerns about this sort of activity?
5. Remember that you may be wrong. It is possible the person has done a good job and will do a good job maintaining this app, and it will be sunshine and rainbows for everyone. Have a plan for this case as well.

Comment: *"There's a reason for organizations to have distinct departments."* - I'm not very convinced about that idea. In an organisation, you have different kinds of managers or function heads, but you don't have a management department, or a department consisting only of function heads, instead these roles are distributed amongst the departments. Similarly, there's no reason why technical staff roles should not be somewhat distributed.

Comment: @Steve, I agree. I did not mean to imply that "distinct departments" represents a Universal Truth. Rather, at any given company, there are reasons for the existing structure. These may be good or bad. They may be flexible or immutable. Thing might just be done by default. My point is that make exceptions or changes to the structure of an organization requires a discussion of the reasons why it got set up that way in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps, but the OP is complaining that higher management have already allowed a "change to the structure" and for development to occur without the developer being a full-time developer line managed by the OP. And the reaction of the OP is typical in that they catastrophise.

Answer (score 8):

Your nose is out of joint because you wouldn't hire [person] to develop web applications, then this other group hired [person] to develop web applications, then [person] developed a web application.

You may be amazed to learn that there are millions of persons *who don't work for you* who want to develop web applications. I don't think you should be allowed to interfere with them.

Comment: Nope, this person was not hired as a developer. They have a general administrative role within another team

Comment: Absolutely irrelevant.

Answer (score 8):

You haven't listed any objective facts at all.

The only thing you said so far is that this person made a web app.

Did you even look at it? Did you assess it at all? How is the security? Password encryption? Redundancy? Backups? Is it coded well?

The whole question reads like you're prejudiced against said person, just because you rejected them based on "lack of experience". I don't even know what experience has to do with anything other than **potentially** lower output, but you have not fairly assessed this person's output at all.

It seems like your ego is a bit bruised since you rejected this hire but another team brought them on and they've successfully made something useful.

Comment: We have reviewed the application and some aspects of it are ok. It is not to a standard that we would release to production.

Comment: What exactly does production mean here? If it is an internal tool, that's different than external, client facing. Your post says "web application to assist in a process within the team", so it's internal. Firewall it in and make it internal only. You don't even need to worry about most things at that point.

Comment: Here's an example of the analysis that I would expect of a competent IT team. Port usage, whether it is hosted on standard 443 or 80. If custom port, then that's going to be firewalled to be internal network only, no exception. If 80, then it is treated as internal only, because it's 2023 and there's no good reason not to use HTTPS. If the SSL certificate is used, I would ask how they plan to maintain it and what webserver daemon they are using, then test it. If it is a Flask/Django/Xampp dev server, internal only. See all these details? All missing. You're not taking this guy seriously.

Comment: Also, "not of a standard we would release" does not mean it isn't better than the previous solution, or lack thereof. Sometimes good enough really is good enough, at least as a starting point. If it has specific issues, work with the author to address this issues, or to provide an alternative they consider acceptable. That isn't "bringing them into your team" , it supporting your "customers" by helping them succeed at their own jobs. IT support would be trivial if it wasn't for those pesky users actually wanting to install and run applications...

Answer (score 3):

Companies are run by management for the benefit of the owners. Keeping employees **happy** is not a goal in itself, but happy employees are often more productive and a good reputation helps a company to attract quality employees. If management wants you to run a certain software, it is their call. Your *job* is to point out pros and cons and then to implement that decision, unless laws are being broken. (Alternatively, you could quit or threaten to quit. But if you make the threat, you should mean it.)

Having said that:

- A professional IT organization does not run software they do not understand, unless external support comes with a proper [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement).
- Before a professional IT organization runs software which is understood by just one employee, it runs a risk analysis.

If you have just two developers, you're on a shoestring. What if one is on vacation and the other gets sick unexpectedly? You should ask your management for the time and budget to review the application from another department for code quality, bugs, and security vulnerabilities. You should also ask management to plan for maintenance of the software (any time there are new browser versions, or patched versions of the software frameworks in use, etc.). If they budget that, fine. If not, point out the risk and decide, for yourself, if you can still work there in good conscience.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is to maybe segregate the application so it's not on your network.  Can you put it on third party shared hosting (hahaha)?  How about putting it on a virtual machine with limited access to your internal network?  In other words, if you can't lock it out completely, put a trench around it so it doesn't poop all over the rest of your IT operations.

What a mess! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> My concerns with this are that I do not want to set a precedent that it is perfectly fine for areas of the business to develop their own applications and expect IT to support them.

You may have to make the argument for why this is liable to be problematic, and more problematic than doing without the application (since that seems to be the alternative you want to impose).

> The application is not at the standard that we would want to release in to production.

What stops you asking for a higher standard to be set?

I've actually been in this position myself a number of times in different businesses, as a person outside the IT department doing what the IT department regarded as work they ought to be doing, but couldn't because of their priorities and overheads relative to their resources.

Fortunately there wasn't a question over the quality of my implementation, though that is certainly always one of the gambits made by the IT department in these situations.

But the decisive reason why management allowed the situation, was that the computers were doing the work that would otherwise have to be done manually by several clerical staff, or would not be done at all and the perceived value lost. It was a one-way bet to allow it to be done.

IT departments often catastrophise about the implications, even before the situation is clear to them, or without even attempting mitigations that don't involve stopping the activity.

A better approach than trying to stamp it out and avoid "precedents", might be to simply oversee the activity instead and try to ensure certain standards are met and quality is sufficient.